# How to update multiple records in MongoDB using node.js by passing bulk array of object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bulkupdate

I want to update mulitiple records in MongoDB by passing bulk array of object in single shot and i am using **node.js** for server side code.

I seen most of the stackover flow questions and answers but it's not relevent with my scenario.

**MongoDB Version : 4.2**

**Node.JS Version : 12**

**Collection Name: users**

**Sample Object: Old Data In MongooDB:**

```
    [{
    _id:"5e84def87f7eb9eed40315e6",
    name:"Sree",
    gender:"female",
    age:21
    },{
    _id:"5e7d989c0fb4a65a1f7b3e0c",
    name:"siva",
    gender:"male",
    age:25
    },{
    _id:"5e7da2cf0fb4a65a1f7b3e0d",
    name:"Yuvi",
    gender:"male",
    age:28
    },{
    _id:"5e84de501612a7c1c07810b8",
    name:"Peeter",
    gender:"male",
    age:21
   }]
```

**Expected Object Should Update in MongoDB:**

```
[{
    _id:"5e84def87f7eb9eed40315e6",
    name:"Sree Siva",
    gender:"female",
    age:26
    },{
    _id:"5e7d989c0fb4a65a1f7b3e0c",
    name:"Siva Palaniappan",
    gender:"male",
    age:35
    },{
    _id:"5e7da2cf0fb4a65a1f7b3e0d",
    name:"Yuvi Gopi",
    gender:"male",
    age:30
    },{
    _id:"5e84de501612a7c1c07810b8",
    name:"Peeter Hey",
    gender:"male",
    age:30
 }]
```

**Sample Object Given From Front End - Through Post API - I am getting below object in payload(request)**

```
{
    "postData":[{
            _id:"5e84def87f7eb9eed40315e6",
            name:"Sree Siva",
            gender:"female",
            age:26
            },{
            _id:"5e7d989c0fb4a65a1f7b3e0c",
            name:"Siva Palaniappan",
            gender:"male",
            age:35
            },{
            _id:"5e7da2cf0fb4a65a1f7b3e0d",
            name:"Yuvi Gopi",
            gender:"male",
            age:30
            },{
            _id:"5e84de501612a7c1c07810b8",
            name:"Peeter Hey",
            gender:"male",
            age:30
         }]
}
```

**Sample Code :**

```
let postObj = req.body.postData;
            postObj.forEach(element => {
                let payLoadObj = {
                    name:element.name,
                    gender:element.gender,
                    age:element.age

                }
                users.updateOne({ _id: element._id}, payLoadObj, (err, updtOrder) => {
                    if (err) {
                        serverErr(err, res);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        if (updtOrder.nModified !== 0) {
                            res.status(200).send({ err: null, data: 'Successfully Updated' });
                        }else{
                           res.status(200).send({ err: null, data: 'Not Updated' });
                        }
                    }
            });
```

**Note:** Based on **_id** we have to update the all the fields without using **forEach** and I tried **arrayFilter** aslo.

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335895/mongodb-updatemany-with-different-set-objects but I think there is no MongoDB API for that.

Comment: @metaphori the above link which is you shared for update multiple - different types of update and we have to set the value for each conditions. below mentioned the sample code

var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { status: "D" } ).update( { $set: { status: "I", points: "0" } } );
bulk.find( { item: null } ).update( { $set: { item: "TBD" } } );
bulk.execute();

This is not usefull for my scenario...

Comment: Yes but I said that I think that MongoDB does not provide a way to update multiple documents at once by passing a corresponding number of "change documents" or, more generally, a function from a matching document to its update logic---also because you could achieve the same by updating one document at a time. Why is the foreach solution not OK to you?

Comment: I hope forEach will be worst case in MongoDB for multiple documents(10k) at a time.
Any way thanks for your effort.